# Pass Variable from jQuery to Angular

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here's my select HTML

```
<label for="SelectMenu">Select the Menu</label><br>
<select id="SelectMenu" name="SelectMenu" ng-init="">
  <?php foreach ($list as $lista): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $lista->MENU_ID; ?>"><?php echo $lista->MENU_NAME; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach;  ?>
</select>
```

I have the following jQuery code to get me the id from any giving option in a select.

```
$("#SelectMenu").change(function() {
var id = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
console.log(id); });
```

And then this Angular Code to fill out a table with ng-repeat.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('dishesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
// var id = 1;
$http.get('http://192.168.1.162/dw/rest/menu_info/' + id)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.info = response.data;
    });
});
```

Here's the table that is populated with the Angular Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-controller="dishesCtrl">
    <th> Dish </th>
    <th> Type</th>
    <th> Price (€)</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in info">
        <td> {{x.DISH_NAME}} </td>
        <td> {{x.DISH_TYPE}} </td>
        <td> {{x.PRICE_VALUE}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that i can't seem to pass the id attribute that i get from jQuery to the $http.get, however if i declare id inside the angular code it works fine.
The idea is that every time someone changes the option for the restaurant in the select it updates the table with the new menu data. Thanks !
Any Suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with your existing code like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('dishesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $("#SelectMenu").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $http.get('http://192.168.1.162/dw/rest/menu_info/' + id)
          .then(function(response) {
              $scope.info = response.data;
        });
    });
});
```

However, it is not the goal of angular to use jQuery for getting a DOM element's value. You should think about using `ng-model` in `<select/>`. This will return you the value of the selected `<option/>` into the $scope variable. See this example:

HTML

```
<select id="SelectMenu" name="SelectMenu" ng-init="" ng-model="SelectMenu.id" ng-change="updateSelectMenu()">
    <?php foreach ($list as $lista): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $lista->MENU_ID; ?>"><?php echo $lista->MENU_NAME; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller('dishesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.SelectMenu = {};

    $scope.updateSelectMenu = function() {
        $http.get('http://192.168.1.162/dw/rest/menu_info/' + $scope.SelectMenu.id)
          .then(function(response) {
              $scope.info = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work either way, the first one with jQuery if i console.log  $scope.id it shows the correct id. 
But in both i get the error 
   >  angular.js:11821 GET http://192.168.1.162/dw/rest/menu_info/undefined

Comment: So i believe angular is not getting the scope variable right.

Comment: I made the first with jQuery Work, changed the closing brackets and parenthesis to the end. But the second approach doesn't work. @ssc-hrep3

Comment: This code snippet was not finished yet. You need to move the $http call of course to a function, which will then be called on a change. I thought that was clear. However, I edited my answer and it should now work.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to make "me too" comments but just to chime in, my life got a lot easier once I realized it's better to just let Angular do all the work.  Maybe a little jQ for animations and the like but even then...

Comment: ssc-hrep3 Yeah, i'm sorry! Kinda new here :D